# Which cell tower is better to point at

Tags: cellular-internet

I live in Ireland, and plan to live in a remote area. The problem is the broadband available through physical means is non-existent (1Mb). With that in mind I've decided to give mobile broadband a try, and set up an antenna to point to the cell tower. My question is which tower would be my best shot:

The "three" provider is the closest according to [cellmapper](https://www.cellmapper.net/map?MCC=272&MNC=5&type=LTE&latitude=52.28976302639646&longitude=-7.468101074218798&zoom=12&showTowers=true&clusterEnabled=true&tilesEnabled=true&heatMapEnabled=false&showOrphans=false&showNoFrequencyOnly=false&showFrequencyOnly=false&showBandwidthOnly=false&DateFilterType=FirstSeen&showHex=false&bands=0,3,20&showVerifiedOnly=false&showUnverifiedOnly=false&showLTECAOnly=false&showBand=0):

but, meteor has a high gain tower a bit further away to the [north west](https://www.cellmapper.net/map?MCC=272&MNC=3&type=LTE&latitude=52.294802731987744&longitude=-7.547408630371142&zoom=12&showTowers=true&clusterEnabled=true&tilesEnabled=true&heatMapEnabled=false&showOrphans=false&showNoFrequencyOnly=false&showFrequencyOnly=false&showBandwidthOnly=false&DateFilterType=FirstSeen&showHex=false&bands=0,3,20&showVerifiedOnly=false&showUnverifiedOnly=false&showLTECAOnly=false&showBand=0):

If anyone has a way of figuring out the range on these towers based on the data on cellmapper, please do share how to figure that out as well!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was the tower to the North. Even though North West was still accessible, the signal was not as strong, I guess in these situations waving the antenna around is always your best option.